# Error al ejecutar pero no al hacer debug

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Cuando hago Debug me funciona pero cuando hago ejecuto no me funciona la acción modificar.

Éste es el código del controlador:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebToxicologiaMVC.DAO;
using WebToxicologiaMVC.Database;
using WebToxicologiaMVC.Main.Module;
using WebToxicologiaMVC.Models;

namespace WebToxicologiaMVC.Controllers
{
    public class ClienteController : Controller
    {
        ClienteManager manager = new ClienteManager();
        TipoDocumentoManager omanager = new TipoDocumentoManager();


        // GET: Cliente
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.TipoDocumentoID = new SelectList(omanager.listarTipoDocumentos(), "TipoDocumentoID", "Descripcion");
            IEnumerable<Cliente> objeto = null;
            objeto = manager.listarClientes();


         return View(objeto);

        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {

          ViewBag.TipoDocumentoID = new SelectList(omanager.listarTipoDocumentos(), "TipoDocumentoID", "Descripcion");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Cliente objeto)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                manager.registrarCliente(objeto);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {

                return View(objeto);
            }
        }




        // GET: Cliente/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }


            // Cliente cliente = ClienteDatos(id);

            Cliente cliente = manager.verCliente(id);

            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(cliente);
        }



        // GET: Cliente/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Cliente cliente = manager.verCliente(id);

            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.TipoDocumentoID = new SelectList(omanager.listarTipoDocumentos(), "TipoDocumentoID", "Descripcion", cliente.TipoDocumentoID);

            return View(cliente);
        }


        // POST: Cliente/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Cliente objeto)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                manager.editarCliente(objeto);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.TipoDocumentoID = new SelectList(omanager.listarTipoDocumentos(), "TipoDocumentoID", "Descripcion", objeto.TipoDocumentoID);
                return View(objeto);


            }




        // GET: Cliente/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Cliente cliente = manager.verCliente(id);
            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(cliente);
        }

        // POST: Cliente/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            Cliente cliente = manager.verCliente(id);
            manager.eliminarCliente(cliente);


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }





    }
}
```

---

Y el modelo:

```
@model WebToxicologiaMVC.Models.Cliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Editar Cliente</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClienteID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nom_Cliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nom_Cliente, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nom_Cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoDocumentoID, "TipoDocumentoID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TipoDocumentoID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoDocumentoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dir_Cliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dir_Cliente, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dir_Cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telef_Cliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telef_Cliente, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telef_Cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Correo_Cliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Correo_Cliente, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Correo_Cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Hola Raúl Eduardo, por favor lee [ask] y edita la pregunta para añadir más información: ¿qué hace el código compartido? ¿qué resultados esperas y cuáles obtienes? ¿recibes algún error al llamar a modificar? ¿dónde y cuál?